# How to hide a modal in Angular 4+?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one component (ModalA) which has a button (openModal) which opens another modalB (another component). I also have a cancel button in modalB, which I would like to reopen ModalA. I am able to hide ModalA, but how can I reopen it?

How can I hide a modal? Currently, I want to hide a modal since another modal opens. I want the other one to be hidden and then show once the user clicks cancel?

The openModal function opens another ModalB, which has a cancel button that when I click on it, it should reopen this modal.

ModalA

```
public openModal(): void {
    const record = { email: this.email, name: this.name, familyName: this.familyName };
    this.DeleteModalComponent.showModal(record);
 }
```

```
<div class="logo">
     <button class="user-modal-form" md-button (click)="openModal()" aria-label="remove">
         <span>Delete user</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the function showModal do opens up a modal?? Please post your code on the component and methods. It is hard to understand what kind of Modal it is?

Comment: the showModal shows the users information

Comment: is it a bootstrap modal angular material modal or some other 3rd part modal. no body will know if you dont post your code.

Comment: Do you have a `closeModal` function? if so call that before your `openModal` function

Comment: yes I am but I want to reopen the other modal

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Bootstrap library which provides necessary components which really makes it easy to use those components with Angular.

```
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    @Component({
     template: `
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, World!</p>
      <p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button></p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
     </div>
     `
    })

    export class NgbdModal1Content {
     constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

     open() {
       this.modalService.open(NgbdModal2Content, {
        size: 'lg'
      });
     }
    }

    @Component({
     template: `
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Hello, World!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
        </div>
      `
    })

    export class NgbdModal2Content {
      constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'ngbd-modal-stacked',
      templateUrl: './modal-stacked.html'
    })

    export class NgbdModalStacked {
      constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

     open() {
       this.modalService.open(NgbdModal1Content);
     }
    }
```

[Modal example from ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

[Working example of nested modals](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/modal/stacked/stackblitz.html)

[ng-bootstrap modal api](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api)

You can even use the "close" method to hide the first modal on opening the second one & use the "open" to show the first one when closing the second modal using the modal api of ng-bootstrap.

I hope these ones help.

Answer (score 0):

I used EventEmitter in ModalB and it worked.

```
  @Output() onHide: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```